# Looking for 4 TB cross-platform filesystem for standalone disk

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ntfs, ntfs-3g

This is partially coming from https://superuser.com/questions/227664/cross-platform-file-system-open-source/1274486#1274486

I have been looking for a filesystem which is supported on both platforms. I have been looking at ext4 and NTFS as two possible filesystems but seem both come short on some counts.

My use-case is an external disk which should be usable on both GNU/Linux and MS-Windows without compromising on disk's life .

a. While ntfs-3g seems to be pretty well supported

http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/changelog.html

But NTFS documentation ( at least according to wikipedia ) seems to be shaky at the best -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS as there doesn't seem to be any versioning as we are used to in GNU/Linux. According to the wikipedia article the last version that is publicly known is 3.1/5.0 which was released for Windows 7.

I had a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383236(v=ws.10).aspx

ex2ifs on the other hand hadn't had a release since 2015.

I also came across this interesting discussion on the MS forums wich gives some ideas of issues with NTFS (especially the caching issues) and ntfs structure damage under Windows 10 as well.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/windows-10-replace-ntfs/eb2394d2-6baa-43cd-bf7c-b727b991daa8?auth=1

I was also looking at btfrs but that seems to be a good choice if you want to have data in RAID configuration only (mirroring of data on different disks for backup, security and failover) but not for standalone disks.

Comment: I think you should ask a different question.  What is the purpose of the disk?  Transferring data between two systems or storage of data to be accessible by both systems?  If the second one, think NAS instead of standalone disk.  You can use ext4 then either create a CIFS share or an NFS share.  There is a component of Windows that will allow it to map and read an NFS share.  Or you can create a CIFS share which Windows will read natively.  Be aware that CIFS has its roots in SMB which has some security issues. (I'm being nice).

Comment: You could try [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=25)

Comment: @Xalorous  I have updated my query which I should have shared before.

Comment: @roaima I'll look into ex2fsd thank you.

Comment: i use NTFS between Linux & Wndows systems without a problem.  Be careful unmounting the drives on each system.  Format the drive on the windows box.

Comment: @DannyK I am not new to computes or even external hdd mounting, unmounting, automounting etc. It is just the way it is atm hence am thinking of buying a new hdd and asking opinions as to what would people recommend.

Comment: @Xalorous I forgot to thank you for sharing the above. I have worked a bit on samba and came to know/experienced some of the issues you are talking about (security nightmare) . IIRC I did see a cartoon or illustration of whack-a-mole in samba although they have been trying to be better.

Comment: Have you considered exFAT?

Comment: @shirish I've used all of the following: an external usb hard drive, an external esata hard drive, hard drive dock and usb drives.  The big question is the interface you want to use.  USB3 has been fast enough for me in most cases using a large 256 or 512 GB USB drive has been more than sufficient.  The keys for my usage have been to format the drive on my windows box and regularly scan the drive.  The drive should be readable on a Mac but I purchased Paragon's NTFS extension so that I can go from Windows or to Linux or to a Mac without any problems.  Hope this answer your question.

Comment: @shirish, I'm with DannyK.  When I need to transfer between Windows and Linux, I use the network, but if one or more machines is not on the network, I use an external USB3 drive formatted with NTFS on the Windows 10 box.  Key things to remember is that external drives are typically not secure and not redundant.  In a business/enterprise setting they should not be used for data storage.  In a private setting, they should not be the only place data is stored.