# what is the version of ntfs when an external disk is partioned under MS-Windows 7

Tags: hard-disk, ntfs, ntfs-3g

This is somewhat related to [Looking for 4 TB cross-platform filesystem for standalone disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408975/looking-for-4-tb-cross-platform-filesystem-for-standalone-disk)

Currently I am posessing a 2 TB external hdd and sometimes the internal ntfs index gets corrupted hence I have to resort to this -

```
> sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb1                                                                                                        [95%]
Mounting volume... $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 28).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 28...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 29...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 30...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 31...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 32...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 33...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 34...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 35...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 36...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 37...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 38...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 39...OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
```

Now I'm not sure whether this hdd was partitioned during Windows XP or Windows 7 as officially even under Windows 7 it is known as NTFS 3.1 (although unofficially known as NTFS 5.0 according to wikipedia.)

I could use smartctl interface to get some more details about when likely the drive was manufactured, it's remaining life etc. I don't think there is anyway to know as they are pre-formatted hdd ( A seagate slim backup)

Has anybody formatted an external hdd in Windows 7 and can share if there is any metadata whhich shows the difference between external hdds created during windows x0 and windows 7 which might give me more idea about the disk and particularly the nfs version it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any Linux OS you can check the version of `NTFS` file system in a drive using

```
sudo ntfsinfo -m  /dev/sdbX | grep Version
```

Omit `grep Version` for full details. Replace `/dev/sdbX` with correct device file. **Unmount** the device before running the above command.

In Windows use open `cmd` as an administrator and use the following to check `NTFS` file system version and other details of your disk.

```
fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo X:
```

Replace `X:` with proper Drive letter.

For information I formatted 4 TB HDD in Windows 7 and `NTFS` version is `3.1`